# Could I use Illusion of Choice to force a opponent to pay tribute?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Could I use [Illusion of Choice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusion%20of%20Choice) to force an opponent to pay tribute?
Does tribute count as voting?

Like first casting Illusion of Choice and then a creature with tribute forcing an opponent to pick the option you want?

Answer (score 9):

Voting doesn't mean choices generally. Voting is just a specific mechanic involving player choice found in some multiplayer sets: [here are the cards that use or reference voting](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28o%3A%2F%5Cbvotes%3F%5Cb%2F+or+o%3Avoting%29+game%3Apaper+prefer%3Aoldest&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name). They all use the word “vote”, and when cards like Illusion of Choice reference voting, they are referring *only* to cards that use that word.

An example is [Capital Punishment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Capital%20Punishment), which says:

> *Council’s dilemma* — Starting with you, each player **votes** for death or taxes. Each opponent sacrifices a creature for each death vote and discards a card for each taxes vote.

Note the actual use of the word “vote” that I've bolded here. [The rules for the Vote mechanic](https://yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#R70132) make it clear that cards talking about “voting” mean this word, not choices generally:

> 701.32c. If the text of a spell or ability refers to "voting," it refers only to an actual vote, not to any spell or ability that involves the players making choices or decisions without using the word "vote."

Tribute ([Fanatic of Xenagos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fanatic%20of%20Xenagos)) has nothing to do with voting. You can't use Illusion of Choice to control your opponent's decision to tribute or not. Cards that simply talk about players “choosing” have no relation to the voting system.

Comment: Thanks , also thanks for the Rules link. I hoped I could use the illusion of choice for sirene of the fanged coast and my orchard elemental next to simply being one of the 99 (Tatyova, Benthic Druid) I will see and wait how much voting is important, or else I am probably going to Replace Illusion.